# Unable to locate element Selenium - the way to jump to next element

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my Problems and Codes

Problems.

1. Almost second wrapper has a button (some second wrapper has a link instead of a button)
2. To avoid second wrapper that contains only link or missing button, I made condition(var:button_check) and if statement.
3. but, these codes works generally but, it always stucks at the wrapper that has link, then throw Message: Unable to locate element: div[role="button"]

```
def clicking_see_more(self) -> None:
    wrappers = self.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[style="text-align: start;"]')
    def button_click():
        for i, wrapper in enumerate(wrappers):
            if i % 2 == 1:
                button_check = bool(wrapper.find_element_by_css_selector('div[role="button"]'))
                    if not button_check:
                        continue
                    else:
                        btn = wrapper.find_element_by_css_selector('div[role="button"]')
                        btn.click()
                        time.sleep(0.5)

    try:
       button_click()
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
       print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `find_elements_by_css_selector` instead of `find_element_by_css_selector`, since `elements` will return a list, you can check for it's size if it is `>0` then element must be present. If not, then element is not present.

try this :

```
def button_click():
    for i, wrapper in enumerate(wrappers):
        button_check = len (driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[role="button"]'))
        if button_check == 0:
            continue
        else:
            btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[role="button"]')
            btn.click()
            time.sleep(0.5)
```